# How to clear form in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How to clear form or after reset event in angular js

```
<form>
   <label>filed 1</label>
   <input type='text'/><br/>
   <label>field 2</label>
   <input type='text'><br/>

   <a href ='javascript:void(0);' class='btn brn-succees'>reset</a>
</form>
```

client js ca not be changed

```
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
  e.curentTarget.reset()
});
```

angular directive

```
auto.fill.form.Directive = ($localstorage) ->

  resetForm = (e) ->
    # load form data  

  restrict: 'E'
  replace: false
  link: (scope, element) ->
    if autoFillElements.length > 0
      element.on 'reset', resetForm


auto.fill.form.Directive.$inject = ['$localstorage']

angular.module ['auto.fill.form', '1.0.0'], []
  .directive 'form', auto.fill.form.Directive
```

it is necessary that the method resetForm is called after purification form

Comment: `$('input').val('')` try this

Comment: you can attach a function to the ng-click event of your reset button that manually sets your ng-model values of your form to their default initial values.

Comment: Can the client html be changed?.. so you can have <input type="text" ng-model="myModel.field1" />

Then you <button ng-click="myModel = {}"></button>

Comment: in the form can not be angular directives and I do not have a model I just attribute of INPUT should set